# Salesforce standard profiles don't access survey obj

Tags: profile, survey, salesforce-survey

As you can see [here](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.concept_create_send_permission.htm&type=5) those profiles can access Survey obj:

- Standard User
- System Admin
- Contract Manager
- Marketing User

In my org, only System Admin users can access the obj even if the other 3 profiles has access to the obj:
This situation can be related to the creation date (2018 pre survey release) of those 4 standard profiles?

Update:
Some system admin users can use surveys and others can't. What's can be different at the user level?